# Integrating Ruby on Rails with Epub.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, epub

We're trying to build an e-reader application that uses Epub.js for the basic loading/viewing functionality. However, we are trying to use Rails 4.0 to build this app, and when we try to integrate Epub.js into our application, we run into some problems.

We tried to follow the Getting Started section on the Github page. We have a Book class to handle the ePub loading. I put the epub.min.js, zip.min.js, and inflate.js files all in the app/assets/javascripts folder. Then, we add the requisite javascript:

```
<script>
var Book = ePub("url/to/book/");
Book.renderTo("area");
</script>
```

Here's where we run into major problems. The argument that ePub() takes is transformed into a url - if it's a local file, then the url would be `http://localhost:3000/books/testbook.epub`, for example. But because of Rail's asset pipeline, we can't have a direct URL link to an asset, meaning that we haven't figured out how to reference a local epub file with a url.

More complications arise from the fact that this doesn't work even if we put a route in routes.rb linking a url directly to the asset, since Epub.js doesn't just look at the epub file; it also uses unpackages it and uses the url to look at its local contents. Also, external urls (like a .epub file from Project Gutenberg) don't work either.

Is there any way around this? I am fairly new to Rails, so I am wondering if there are any key areas that I am overlooking. Would there be any modiifications to Epub.js that I would have to make? I've scoured Google and StackOverflow for answers, but there don't seem to be many projects integrating Rails and Epub.js. I've also tried other solutions, like Readium.js, and they also don't seem to be working.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I have a lot of questions. What does it mean exactly "if it's a local file"? Are we talking local to a user (meaning located on his computer) or local for a server (located on the server)? Second, I am not sure why do you want to have direct URL link to an asset. Asset folders is for javascript, css and you should pub books in public folder (if you want them to be accessible from outside). Also, what happens if you point to external pubs? What doesn't work?

Comment: One more thing. Generally speaking, as soon as web page is created and spitted out to a browser, rails doesn't have anything to do with it. So, problems with handling external URL should be in the javascrpt (your code or ePub.js code)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the library available on the public folder. This folder is not affected by the assets pipeline. You do not have to secure its contents too since it is already available. So I see no problem in using it from the public folder.

Simply drop it on rails_root/public and load it in your application layout normally

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/public/epub.js" %>
```

hope it helps